# apply runtime metadatatype for validation

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I need to have different validation for the same object. So I thought to use Metadatatype to define the different rules the code is below:

```
public class ValidateObjectAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly Type _validationMetaDataType;

    public ValidateObjectAttribute(Type validationMetaDataType)
    {
        _validationMetaDataType = validationMetaDataType;
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {            
        var modelType = value.GetType();
        AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider associatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider = null;
        if (_validationMetaDataType != null)
        {
            associatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider = new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(modelType, _validationMetaDataType);
            TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(associatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider, modelType);
        }

        var validationctx = new ValidationContext(value);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(value, validationctx, results, true);

        if (associatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider != null)
        {
            TypeDescriptor.RemoveProvider(associatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider, modelType);
            TypeDescriptor.Refresh(value);

        }

        if (results.Count == 0) return ValidationResult.Success;

        return new ValidationResult($"Validation fail for prop: {validationContext.DisplayName}");
    }

}

public class BarMetaData1
{
    [Required]
    public string BarField1;
    [Required]
    public string BarField2;
}

public class FooMetaData1
{
    [Required]
    public string FooField1;
    [Required]
    public string FooField2;
    [Required, ValidateObject(typeof(BarMetaData1))]
    public Bar FooObject1;
}

public class FooMetaData2
{
    public string FooField1;
    [Required]
    public string FooField2;
    [Required, ValidateObject(typeof(BarMetaData1))]
    public Bar FooObject1;
}

public class BaseValidation
{
    public bool IsValid(Type validationMetaDataType)
    {

        var modelType = this.GetType();
        AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider associatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider = null;
        if (validationMetaDataType != null)
        {
            associatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider = new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(modelType, validationMetaDataType);
            TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(associatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider, modelType);
            TypeDescriptor.Refresh(this);
        }

        var validationctx = new ValidationContext(this);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(this, validationctx, results, true);

        if (associatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider != null)
        {
            TypeDescriptor.RemoveProvider(associatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider, modelType);
        }

        return results.Count == 0;
    }

    
}



public class Foo : BaseValidation
{
    public string FooField1 { get; set; }
    public string FooField2 { get; set; }
    public Bar FooObject1 { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string BarField1 { get; set; }
    public string BarField2 { get; set; }
}
```

the validation is call in this way:

```
public void Index()
    {
        Foo fooInstance = new Foo()
        {
            FooObject1 = new Bar()
        };
        fooInstance.IsValid(typeof(FooMetaData2));

        fooInstance.IsValid(typeof(FooMetaData1));

        Foo fooInstance2 = new Foo()
        {
            FooObject1 = new Bar()
        };

        fooInstance2.IsValid(typeof(FooMetaData2));

    }
```

What is the issue:

- first validation [fooInstance.IsValid(typeof(FooMetaData2))] is right (2 mandatory fields missing),
- second validation call [fooInstance.IsValid(typeof(FooMetaData1))] the result is wrong (3 mandatory field missing but the code notify me only 2), it seems that the code apply the validation describe in FooMetaData2 class instead of FooMetaData1

Someone can explain to me why?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using fluentValidator plugin